# How to remove fragment on Button Click?

Tags: android, fragment

I have an expandable `ListView` in my `MainActivity`. When certain item on the child `ListView` is selected some buttons (install, detail, cancel) are shown in `fragment`.

```
lv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(!status){
                    final Options op = new Options();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main,op);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }
```

Here Options is my `fragment's` name. Pressing the cancel button in the Options class i want to remove this fragment and display only the `MainActivity`.

```
Button btnCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
      btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //REMOVE THIS FRAGMENT

        }
    });
```

Can anybody please tried help me?

Comment: @AmitVaghela In that ques the fragment is shown and hidden from same class. but in my ques the fragment is shown by clicking on child listview on main activity  and removed from the fragment class using cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

To Remove all `Fragments`

```
public void clearAllFragments() {

    try {
        FragmentManager aFragmentManager = Context
            .getSupportFragmentManager();

        aFragmentManager.popBackStack(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To Remove a single `Fragment`

```
public void removeFragment(int aCount) {

    FragmentManager aFragmentManager = Context
            .getSupportFragmentManager();

    for (int i = 0; i < aCount; i++) {

        aFragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
}
```